# Combine/Sync Amazon S3 and MongoDB Atlas with Elastic Search

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x, aws, elasticsearch

I have many continuously growing (through scrapping) collections in MongoDB Atlas. The documents in each collection follows the following schema:

```
{
"source_url": "<some url on the web>",
"html": "<S3 url>",
"text": "<S3 url>",
"source": "<data source>",
}
```

The `html` and `text` are `Amazon S3` urls of extracted html and text from the `source_url`.

I want to save/sync all these information in Elasticsearch with following form of the document structure:

```
{
"source_url": "<some url on the web>",
"html": "<html from S3 url>",
"text": "<text from S3 url>",
"source": "<data source>",
}
```

I can write a `python` script that saves all the existing data in elastic search and then periodically looks for new entries (**all entries in MongoDb minus existing entries in ES**) and save the data to ES.

This however, seems to much of a work to me and there must be a way so that as soon as there is an entry into MongoDB, some service does all the work and sends data to ES.

Any help in making this work efficient will be appreciated and if there are any known solutions for these types of tasks, please specify.